# Non Admin User can not generate pdf and email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using the following code (help received from @Tanaike, @Rafa Guillermo) to generate a PDF of my sheet from which this function is triggered in turn the PDF is emailed with the email ID present in the sheet. This code works very nicely when the admin user triggers the function but when a editor tries to do the same he gets an error as below:

> Exception: You are trying to edit a protected cell or object. Please contact the spreadsheet owner to remove protection if you need to edit.

I tried to use the `doget(e)` to run the function but that results in various errors in the script.

Can anyone help me out.

```js
function generatePdf() {
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  hideImageall(); //my custom function
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); // Get active spreadsheet.
  var sheets = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheets(); // Get active sheet.
  var sheetName = sourceSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var pdfName = sheetName + ".pdf"; // Set the output filename as SheetName.
  var parents = DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).getParents(); // Get folder containing spreadsheet to save pdf in.
  if (parents.hasNext()) {
    var folder = parents.next();
  } else {
    folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  }
  var theBlob = createblobpdf(sheetName, pdfName);
  var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() || 'admin@domain.com';
  var custemail = sourceSheet.getRange('C9').getValue();
  email = email + "," + custemail;
  // Subject of email message
  const subject = `Quotation for Inquiry Attachement: ${sheetName}`;
  // Email Body can  be HTML too with your logo image 
  const body = "<p>Dear Sir,</p><p>BODY</p><p>We hope for the best response from your side.</p><p>Regards";
  if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0)
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments: [theBlob]
    });
  // delete pdf if already exists
  var files = folder.getFilesByName(pdfName);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    files.next().setTrashed(true);
  }
  showimage(); //my custom function
  sourceSpreadsheet.toast("Quotation Emailed to " + email, "Success");

}

function showimage() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('ID');
  file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
  var img = file.getBlob();
  ss.insertImage(img, 9, 6).setHeight(35).setWidth(130).assignScript("createDO").setAltTextTitle("createdo");
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
};

function createblobpdf(sheetName, pdfName) {
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + sourceSpreadsheet.getId() + '/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
    +'&size=A4' // paper size legal / letter / A4
    +'&portrait=true' // orientation, false for landscape
    +'&fitw=true' // fit to page width, false for actual size
    +'&sheetnames=true&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
    +'&pagenum=RIGHT&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
    +'&fzr=false' // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    +'&horizontal_alignment=CENTER' //LEFT/CENTER/RIGHT
    +'&vertical_alignment=TOP' //TOP/MIDDLE/BOTTOM
    +'&gid=' + sourceSheet.getSheetId(); // the sheet's Id
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  // request export url
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    }
  });
  var theBlob = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName);
  return theBlob;
};

function hideImage() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var image = ss.getImages(); // assuming this is the only image
  for (var i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
    var imagename = image[i].getAltTextTitle();
    if (imagename == "NQ") {
      image[i].remove();
    };
    if (imagename == "NDO") {
      image[i].remove();
    };
  };
}

function hideImageall() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var image = ss.getImages();
  for (var i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
    var imagename = image[i].getAltTextTitle();
    if (imagename != "Logo") {
      if (imagename != "Sign") {
        image[i].remove();
      }
    };
  };
}

function doGet(e) {
  if (e.parameter.function == "Protect") {
    script();
    return ContentService.createTextOutput();
  } else if (e.parameter.function == "AddRows") {
    Addrows(e.parameter.sheetName, e.parameter.notoAdd);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput();
  } else { // do something by default if there are no url parameters
    throw new Error("function was not found.");
    //return ContentService.createTextOutput();
  }
}

const url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() + "?function=";

function Protect() {
  // const url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "Protect", {
    headers: {
      authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    }
  });
  // DriveApp.getFiles()  // This is used for automatically detecting the scope of "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly". This scope is used for the access token.
}

var sheetname = "";
var notoadd = 0;

function AddRows() {
  //const url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  notoadd = showPrompt();
  sheetname = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName();
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "AddRows&sheetName=" + sheetname + "&notoAdd=" + notoadd, {
    headers: {
      authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    }
  });
  // DriveApp.getFiles()  // This is used for automatically detecting the scope of "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly". This scope is used for the access token.
}

function script() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var myValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetName();
  spreadsheet.duplicateActiveSheet();
  var totalSheets = countSheets() - 2;
  totalSheets = totalSheets - 2;
  myValue = "Q2000" + totalSheets;
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().renameActiveSheet(myValue);
  var protection = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().protect();
  protection.setUnprotectedRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('C7:F10'), spreadsheet.getRange('C11:E12'), spreadsheet.getRange('G10:H10'), spreadsheet.getRange('H11'), spreadsheet.getRange('G12:H12'), spreadsheet.getRange('B16:G24')])
    .removeEditors(['user1@domain.com', 'user2@domain.com']);
  spreadsheet.getRange('H7').setValue(myValue);
  spreadsheet.getRange('I1:I').clearContent();
  hideImage();

};
```

Answer (score 0):

#### See if you have any protected ranges

Go to the menu:

[image]

In the sidebar that appears:

[image]

You may see a range, click it and choose the option to delete that protected range.

Comment: Yes it does have protected range but the other functions work properly with all the protected ranges and only this function to generate pdf is not working with users.

Comment: Maybe the other functions only need to read and the generate pdf needs write permissions?

Comment: Do you get the error on any particular line in the function? What does the executions page say?

Comment: Execution page gives the following error: 
Jan 20, 2021, 10:17:58 PM Error Exception: You are trying to edit a protected cell or object. Please contact the spreadsheet owner to remove protection if you need to edit.
    at hideImageall(Code:109:30)
    at generatePdf(PDF:4:3)

Comment: @Harsh  It seems to be a problem with the function `hideImageall` - the line numbers in what you pasted do not add up to the error message, so not sure on which line it fails. Could it be `image[i].remove();` when it fails? If you comment out line 4 in your `generatePdf` function, `// hideImageall()` so that it does not run, does it work then? Are you able to share a sanitized copy of the sheet?

Comment: it is giving error in the first line of hideimageall code when it it called and tries to access the current spreadsheet. I will not be able to sanitize the sheet to share as it has lot of data

Comment: It can't be the first line, because elsewhere in your code you call the same thing and it doesn't give you that error? I want to try to reproduce your situation, but I don't know how to do this because it seems there are a few sheets with specific data and even calls to specific folders in Drive, so I don't know how to test it to see what might be the problem. I have tried running the script but I get errors related to the fact that I don't have a specific file on Drive. Please see [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: can you please share your email id so that i can share the complete code with you

Comment: I am sorry, I think its against Stack Overflow guidelines. The point of Stack Overflow is that questions and answers can be useful to future users, if we are in contact privately then what is the point of having this question here? I think its best for you to come up with a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - Here is also a great article that will definitely help debug your code - https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @iansedano. I have made a new sheet with minimum data in a new file and not on my company account and sharing it with you https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gNgGFL-obU3oB_9WEsK0IFUdJ4VQQMgKEiDJIH7hSVM/edit?usp=sharing